# No WebGL support in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, webgl

I set **Override software rendering list** and **Enable WebGL** in `chrome://flags` but http://get.webgl.org says I don't have WebGL support.

I also tried running chrome with `--disable-gpu-watchdog` but it doesn't help. Firefox runs WebGL just fine. I have the same issue with chromium-browser package (39.0.2171.65 Ubuntu 14.10) and also with Chrome (39.0.2171.71).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This solved it:

I launch Google Chrome using

```
LIBGL_DRI3_DISABLE=1 google-chrome
```

Found the solution [here on code.google.com](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=418858)